# PHP to get files from another server

Tags: php, ftp, fileserver

We have a server running PHP (windows). We've run out of HD space with our ISP and set up an account on another server (Linux) for file storage.

What is the best method for running the script in one environment, but getting/putting files to another.

If you have any examples I'd appreciate any pointers. Not sure is we should just look into an (s)ftp connection or a better method.

The files on the linux box will NOT be web accessible (above the http)

Thanks,
D

Comment: buy some real web hosting, less hassle than this approach

Comment: wish that were an option

Comment: politics, pre-paid setup, connections to an association that needs the main server where it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both servers are on the same LAN, install Samba on the Linux server and map a Windows drive to it.

I did this for a Windows app that needed a terabyte of fault-tolerant storage for audio files.

Comment: So basically on the linux box we'd set up SMB and then map it in windows like "z:\path\to\stuff" then reference it like it was on the local windows box, right?